# How to create notification in Android with API 21 or higher

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I have trouble creating notification from the application in Android. API must be API 21 or higher. I've probably tried 100 ways with Android Developer and other websites.

minSDK must be API21

I opened it on API26

This is my activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click for Notification"
        android:id="@+id/buckysButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="buckysButtonClicked" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is MainActivity.java

```
        package pl.wat.pz.notification;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.NotificationManager;
        import android.app.PendingIntent;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
    private static final int uniqueID = 45612;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notification.setAutoCancel(true);
    }

    public void buckysButtonClicked(View view){
        //Build the notification
        notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notification.setTicker("This is the ticker");
        notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setContentTitle("Here is the title");
        notification.setContentText("I am the body text of your notification");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        //Builds notification and issues it
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(uniqueID, notification.build());

    }
    }
```

And the manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pl.wat.pz.notification">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

And here image from android emulator

[After click button nothing happened ;((](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Yub.png)

Comment: And what exactly is the issue you're having? This question is unclear as is.

Comment: After clicking the button, the notification should show up, but nothing happens on notification bar

Comment: You mention a lot about an API version level in your question -- is that from an error message?

Comment: This is my requirement for the application, the application has to work on api 21 or higher, which you do not understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

AFAIK, you cannot use a `mipmap` resource here, and your launcher icon is *not* a suitable notification icon on Android 4.4 and higher.

Create a separate drawable resource for your notification icon. If you are using Android Studio, the Image Asset wizard can assist with this.

Also, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 26 or higher, you need to set up a [notification channel](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels) when running on Android 8.0+. [This directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/Notifications) contains many sample apps that are up-to-date with respect to raising a `Notification`.

Comment: Which from Asset Wizard take:
1)Launcher Icons
2)Action bar and tab icons
3)Notification icons
.??

Comment: I change for Action bar and tab icons and Notification icons and still nothing happened ;(

Comment: @zajkoo16: See the updated answer for another possible problem with your app, plus links to working sample apps.

Comment: It works, Thanks a lot ;)))))))  After 3 days of hard battle IT WORKS ;)